# convert to std_logic_vector and slice more efficiently

Tags: vhdl

Inside a process I do some work on `UNSIGNED` vectors which I need to slice and cast back to a `SLV` at the end of the process. Is there a nicer/cleaner way than this?

```
    out_O : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
    variable o : UNSIGNED(17 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    variable outcast_t : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    ...

    o := mod_t - div_t + const;

    outcast_t := STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(o);
    out_O <= outcast_t(15 downto 0);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the intermediate signal : `out_O <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(o(15 downto 0));` ought to work

Comment: oh, i was slicing after the cast. this is good news and a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;
```

slv will be handled as unsigned and you can do your operations on that type directly such that you avoid casting.

You can also do something like this

```
out_O <= o(out_O'range);
```

which may save you some changes if the size of `out_O` is modified. Assuming that you redefined `o` as slv.

Comment: Using `IEEE.numeric_std_unsigned` is not recommended.

Comment: @Paebbels Personally I don't mind conversions. Sometimes my bit array is a number and I may use the unsigned type, sometimes it's transferred on a generic data bus and becomes a slv. Depending on the situation one datatype feels more "native" and I don't mind casting back and forth to express that design intent . Some people do mind and rather have just slv. Some people would use numeric_std_unsigned in testbenches but not in RTL to avoid synthesis support issues. The recommendation is likely to depend on situation and who you ask